# After 302 redirect, browser redirect to wrong location after implicit Oauth2 authentication, and access token fragment missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, implicit

I have an Oauth2 authorization server based on springboot 2.

I have an application SPA based on react.js.

I want to generate an accessToken , for that i chose the implicit garant_type.
the flow working well, i get the access_token, but can't read the access_token fragment from my front application. The browser dont redirect to the 302 location www.example.com/conetext-path/index.hrml#access_token=azerty, the browser redirect to www.example.com/conetext-path/ and the fragment disappears.

See below the different exchanges with the server:

> **1-**
>   GET https://www.example.com/api/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my-trusted-client&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/context-apth/index.html&scope=read

**RESPONSE:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS,TRACE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 19:01:56 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: https://www.example.com/context-path/login
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

> 2- POST https://www.example.com/context-path/login with credentials

**RESPONSE:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS,TRACE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 19:05:35 GMT
Expires: 0 
Location: https://www.example.com/api/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my-trusted-client&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/context-apth/index.html&scope=read
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B08832A4F924A500DBB5C8F38034996D; Path=/api/auth; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

> **3-**  302 redirect result after login

**RESPONSE**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS,TRACE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: fr-FR
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 19:05:35 GMT
Location: https://www.example.com/context-path/index.html#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsib2F1dGgyLXJlc291cmNlIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IkFnZW50X21haGRpX2thbGxlbCIsIlRFTkFOVF9DUkVDSEUiOjEsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTcwNDE4NzM1LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJBR0VOVF9DUkVDSEVfTk9OX0NPTkZJUk1FIiwiQUdFTlRfQ1JFQ0hFX0NPTkZJUk1FIiwiQURNSU5fQ1JFQ0hFIl0sImp0aSI6ImJmYzUzN2Y2LTA2ZDgtNGUxMS1hNTA3LTc0ZmRlNDgzMzVhNCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im15LXRydXN0ZWQtY2xpZW50In0.qoEEBIy2x-ABlXIEYeilfW-X4U8sOMTdZrEqLWFJ4Kc&token_type=bearer&expires_in=30000
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

> **4-** im redirected to /index.html:

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 18:48:22 GMT
ETag: W/"5d989034-a83"
Last-Modified: Sat, 05 Oct 2019 12:44:36 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1250
```

**but on the browser location i see the url https://www.example.com/context-path/ instead of https://www.example.com/context-path/index.html.**

Inside index.html I have a javascript script looking for the fragment access_token, but its null.

I don't understand why the browser not redirecting to the location with the fragment.

Comment: Possibly an issue with your code - a bunch of response headers doesn't give any idea to what the code is

Comment: 1. Check: the ngix server paths and rules, maybe the path *index.html* is translated into **/**. 2. Try to copy/paste the full url http:/..../index.html#token=... and see what append. 3. Check the app redirect url

Comment: @Max when i call again https://www.example.com/api/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my-trusted-client&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/context-apth/index.html&scope=read on the browser, everything is ok, the broswer redirect me after to https://www.example.com/context-path/index.html#access_token=sdfkslkdflksf&token_type=bearer&expires_in=30000
 and i can read the fragment, i don't see whats the diffrence between the first and the second redirect